# How to implement switch in react native using the below code?

Tags: react-native, user-interface, react-hooks, conditional-statements, rendering

I've been learning React Native and was trying to create a settings screen. The problem is that the switch isn't working.

The code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {  StyleSheet,  View,  TouchableOpacity,  Text,  Switch,  SafeAreaView,  Image,} from 'react-ative';
import FeatherIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';

const SECTIONS = [
  {
    header: 'Preferences',
    items: [
      { icon: 'globe', label: 'Language', value: 'English', type: 'input' },
      { icon: 'moon', label: 'Dark Mode', value: false, type: 'boolean' },
      { icon: 'wifi', label: 'Use Wi-Fi', value: true, type: 'boolean' },
    ],
  },
  {
    header: 'Help',
    items: [
      { icon: 'flag', label: 'Report Bug', type: 'link' },
      { icon: 'mail', label: 'Contact Us', type: 'link' },
    ],
  },
  {
    header: 'Content',
    items: [
      { icon: 'save', label: 'Saved', type: 'link' },
      { icon: 'download', label: 'Downloads', type: 'link' },
    ],
  },
];

function SectionRow({ label, value, type, index, onPress }) {
  return (
    <View style={[{ marginLeft: 12 }, index !== 0 && styles.splitline]}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
        <View style={styles.sectionBodyRow}>
          <Text style={styles.sectionBodyRowLabel}>{label}</Text>
          <View style={styles.spacer} />
          {type === 'input' && (
            <Text style={styles.sectionBodyRowValue}>{value}</Text>
          )}
          {type === 'boolean' && <Switch value={value} />}
          {(type === 'input' || type === 'link') && (
            <FeatherIcon
              style={{ marginLeft: 6 }}
              name="chevron-right"
              size={24}
              color="#ababab"
            />
          )}
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

export default function Example() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Settings</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.section}>
        <View style={styles.sectionHeader}>
          <Text style={styles.sectionHeaderText}>Account</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.profile}>
          <Image
            alt=""
            source={{
              uri: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633332755192-727a05c4013d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2.5&w=256&h=256&q=80',
            }}
            style={styles.profileAvatar}
          />

          <View style={styles.profileBody}>
            <Text style={styles.profileName}>John Doe</Text>

            <Text style={styles.profileHandle}>john.doe@mail.com</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>

      {SECTIONS.map(({ header, items }) => (
        <View style={styles.section} key={header}>
          <View style={styles.sectionHeader}>
            <Text style={styles.sectionHeaderText}>{header}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.sectionBody}>
            {items.map(({ label, type, value }, index) => {
              const isFirst = index === 0;
              const isLast = index === items.length - 1;
              return (
                <View
                  key={index}
                  style={[
                    styles.rowWrapper,
                    index === 0 && { borderTopWidth: 0 },
                    isFirst && styles.rowFirst,
                    isLast && styles.rowLast,
                  ]}>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => {
                      // handle onPress
                    }}>
                    <View style={styles.row}>
                      <Text style={styles.rowLabel}>{label}</Text>

                      <View style={styles.rowSpacer} />

                      {type === 'input' && (
                        <Text style={styles.rowValue}>{value}</Text>
                      )}

                      {type === 'boolean' && <Switch value={value} />}

                      {(type === 'input' || type === 'link') && (
                        <FeatherIcon
                          color="#ababab"
                          name="chevron-right"
                          size={22}
                        />
                      )}
                    </View>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              );
            })}
          </View>
        </View>
      ))}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

I think I should use useState but I'm confused how to use it in the above code.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Saying something "isn't working" doesn't give us a lot of clues to work with. If you get an error, please include the whole error message. If not, please add more detail about what's happening. See [ask] when you can. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The value of the switch won't set itself. You have to  add handler like this

`onValueChange={value => setValue(value)}`

to see the value of the switch change and use it later